# Debug DLLs in bin folder (SP 2013)

Tags: debugging

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 Foundation.

I have configured Form Based Authentication.

I wrote my own project to do the authentication (compiled into a DLL).

Placed both DLL and PDB files in "FOLDER_OF_SP_SITE\bin" folder

I want to know how to debug this DLL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the w3wp process running this site (you can find out which w3wp process it is by running C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list wp) from the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: Hi Trevor, Thanks! I have tried it, but doesn't work.. it doesn't break.. any idea..?